# Leaflet map-event 'load' does not fire

Tags: javascript, leaflet, onload

I am trying to call a function after a leaflet map has successfully loaded, working with leaflet 1.0.1. Regarding to the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html) there is a map event named [`load`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-load) which states: *Fired when the map is initialized (when its center and zoom are set for the first time)*. So this snipped should fire, if the map has loaded, but that never happens:

```
function onMapLoad() {
    alert("Map successfully loaded")
};

mymap.on('load', onMapLoad);
```

There is no error or response, simple nothing.
So why is the map-load event not working properly ?

Here goes a simple [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bnuwhw70/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put the `mymap.on('load', onMapLoad);` event handler before you actually load the map (with `map.setView...`).

So your actual code should look like,

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid');
mymap.on('load', onMapLoad);
mymap.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Source : [Github Issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/610)

Answer (score 26):

I suggest you to use the "whenReady" method available in Leaflet 1.0.1

```
var callBack = function () {
    console.log("Map successfully loaded");
    // do some stuff
};

mymap.whenReady(callBack);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use inline

```
var mymap = L.map('YOUR_MAP_ID').on('load', onMapLoad).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

function onMapLoad(){
  console.log("map loaded");
}
```